# Sitecore 7.2 - Coveo/rest is throwing the error "The service is unavailable."

Tags: coveo

I have installed Coveo for sitecore 3.0 in my local/developer machine. Search indexes are having content in CES and but when I search,  my search page does not return any results or coveo facets does not appear. So, I tried to access the url "http://mywebsite.com/coveo/rest" and it is throwing the below error.

"The service is unavailable."

I have checked and compared config.yml's secret key and application secret key in coveosearchprovider.config. Both looks same.
Sitecore diagnostic page shows the below.

[image]

Can you please let me know the things I should check to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the port which is used for SearchApi and found that I am using a different port for SearchApi rather than normal 8080 one. I have now updated the Coveo.SearchProvider.Rest.config with the correct port and was able to get the results in Searchresults page.